# Cuda invalid documentation

Tags: cuda

```
__constant__ float constData[256];
float data[256];
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(constData, data, sizeof(data));
cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(data, constData, sizeof(data));
__device__ float devData;
float value = 3.14f;
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(devData, &value, sizeof(float));
__device__ float* devPointer;
float* ptr;
cudaMalloc(&ptr, 256 * sizeof(float));
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(devPointer, &ptr, sizeof(ptr));
```

This is an example taken from nvidia's website. According to the same site, the signature for cudaMemcpyToSymbol takes a pointer as it's first argument. The variable devData is not a pointer and still being used in place of one. How is this possible? I also realize that signature has changed, but why would this make sense in any context? Would that be a valid argument as the symbol to the new functions as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation for the [C++ version of cudaMemcpyToSymbol()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__HIGHLEVEL_1g0c15b63c7b065fda8998713831edcbc7).

Comment: This is an example from the cuda c guide

Comment: And it is correct. Have you tried compiling it and run into problems or are you just saying that according to your understanding it should not work?

Comment: I admit that the documentation for cudaMemcpyToSymbol() is confusing, particularly as it evolved over time. But the code above is correct, as far as I can tell without running it.

Comment: I'm studying in preparation for a experiment, in which I will be remotely running the code. I currently don't have access to any card that runs CUDA. Will this function work with any CUDA setup, or does something need to be added to run the C++ like functions.

Comment: It will work with any setup, as long as you use `nvcc` to compile the code (which is the normal way of compiling CUDA code). 
Let me applaud you for getting this far with only the documentation! I believe it is very difficult to get to know CUDA without some hands-on experience with an actual GPU.